# Moving to the UK with my French wife

Tags: eu-spouses

What do I need to apply for a visa to visit the UK with my French wife? If possible stay and work there.

I've spent 25 years in English, African, and Asian countries. I've come to know that the English and French lifestyles are a bit different.

Comment: I assume you are not an EU citizen?  If so, you should probably move fast - if a no-deal Brexit happens, your wife may not be able to move to the UK, or may not be able to bring you.

Answer (score 1):

You would start by applying for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).  This allows you to visit the UK with your wife.  It also allows you to enter the UK with the intention of remaining there with her under the EU right of free movement.

To work, you will want a [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card).  You don't require one to be authorized to work or stay, but your employer will need to see it to comply with the law that requires employers to verify their employees' right to work.  Practically speaking you need to apply for one.